# Confidence Intervals from Coefficient of Variation and mean

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, coefficient-of-variation

I apologize if the answer to this is obvious.  Either 1) obviously not possible or 2) obviously simple.

I have an equation which gives 95% confidence interval lower bound (97.75%) of fatigue life prediction based on material properties, assuming 2 standard deviations from the mean and standard error around a parameter.

For the material I am dealing with I don't know the standard error (SE).  What I have from reviewing "the literature" (many articles) is a good sense of what the Coefficient of Variation (SV) could be for the material property.

I don't think I can just substitute CV for SE and think I am doing things correctly.  But I feel like it is close.  The elements are there.  What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a sample size for the literature studies? If you have the Coefficient of Variation of the parameter and a reasonable estimate of the mean, you can estimate the standard deviation of the parameter. But you need to know how precise the parameter estimate is, which will require knowing the sample size it was estimated from. The CoV or standard deviation tells you about relative variability in the population, but the precision of parameter estimates depends on N.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but let's say I don't have N. If the equation I was given for confidence doesn't use N, just SE, am I still in the same spot?  Or is there an inherent flaw in my equation?

Comment: Well, SE depends on N, so that should get you close to what you need, but CoV doesn't depend on N. Statistics like standard deviation or mean or CoV describe the population you're measuring, but don't say anything about the precision of your parameter estimates, and do not depend on N. SE, on the other hand, describes variability of the parameters, not variability of the population, and does depend on N. The width of the confidence interval on your fatigue life prediction depends on how precisely you measured the underlying property (moreso with more N), but not what that value actually is.